# Access and modify a specific part of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string that looks like this:

```
'"a": "...",
"b": "...",
"c": "...",
"d": "...",
"text": "Part to access and modify",
"f": "...",
"g": "..."'
```

And i would like to access to the text after `'"text":'`.
The way I do it now is `const text = str.split('"text": ')[1].split('"')[1]` and thanks to that I can access and modify my text.
I don't know if there is a more efficient method but my biggest problem is to succeed in replacing the old text with the new text in the basic structure.

How can i do it please ?

Before:

```
'"a": "...",
"b": "...",
"c": "...",
"d": "...",
"text": "Part to access and modify",
"f": "...",
"g": "..."'
```

After:

```
'"a": "...",
"b": "...",
"c": "...",
"d": "...",
"text": "Modified text",
"f": "...",
"g": "..."'
```

Comment: This looks like JSON content and it would be best/safest to use a parser, rather than regex.

Comment: Where are you getting that string value from? It would be a far better use of your time to correct that output to something which can be easily parsed (as @TimBiegeleisen suggested) instead of spending time hacking together a brittle solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind assertion regex:

```js
let str = `"a": "...",
"b": "...",
"c": "...",
"d": "...",
"text": "Part to access and modify",
"f": "...",
"g": "..."`;

str = str.replace(/(?<="text": ")[^"]+/, 'Modified text');

console.log(str);
```

It also looks like a part of an object literal, so:

```js
let str = `"a": "...",
"b": "...",
"c": "...",
"d": "...",
"text": "Part to access and modify",
"f": "...",
"g": "..."`;

const obj = JSON.parse(`{${str}}`);
obj.text = 'Modified text';

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2).split('\n').slice(1, -1).map(line => line.trim()).join('\n'));
```

Comment: You beat me to it with line for line IDENTICAL code for the JSON parsing ;)

Comment: @mplungjan i see, it was fun)

Comment: I considered `.slice(2,-2)` (and decided to not bother because of the leading spaces I see you added a map for)  but I still think it is an X/Y problem

Comment: @mplungjan i trimmed lines also, but yes, seems X/Y

Comment: I know. great minds etc.-

Answer (score 1):

This looks like JSON content and it would be best/safest to use a parser, rather than regex.  That being said, you could use regex here as follows:

```js
var input = `"a": "...",
"b": "...",
"c": "...",
"d": "...",
"text": "Part to access and modify",
"f": "...",
"g": "..."`;

input = input.replace(/"text":\s*".*?"/, '"text": "Modified text"');
console.log(input);
```